# Division problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I came across these problems :

> 1) Find the lowest natural number $k$ that satisfies the condition :
>
> $ 7 \mid A$ , where $A = 194^{19} + 125^{14} + k $
>
> 2) Find the different prime numbers $m, n, p$, that satisfy the condition :
>
> $$2mnp - m - n - p - mn - mp - np \le 19$$

For the first one, I'm thinking at Fermat's little theorem..

Some hints would really help me.

Comment: Hint for 1: You might want to use modulo arthimetic and Fermat's Little theorem to work out the remainder when $194^{19}$ and $125^{14}$ are divided by 7. For example, $194^{19} \equiv 5^{19} \equiv 5$ (mod 7)

Comment: @suncup224 thanks, got it. I steel have trouble with the second one.

Comment: For 2: This is not a systematic approach, but seeing how $mnp$ will blow up much faster than $m,n,p,mn,mp,np$, so in order to keep the left hand side small, it seems natural to try the smallest possible primes. So I tried $m=2, n=3, p=5$ and it works. Are you supposed to find all possible solutions, or just one set?

Comment: @suncup224 all possible solutions.

Comment: @suncup224 in the first comment you posted, why $5^{19}≡5 (mod 7)$ ?

Comment: $5^{19} = (5^6)^3 * 5$ and $5^6 \equiv 1$ (mod 7) by Fermat's Little Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(194)^19 = -2 (mod 7)

(125)^14 = 1 (mod 7)

194^19 + (125)^14 + K = 0 (mod 7)

-2 + 1 + k = 0 (mod 7)

the minimum natural number for k is 1

k = 1

Comment: I think that you mean $125^{14} = -1 (mod 7)$, right?

Comment: no, 125 = -1 (mod 7)   , (125)^14 = (-1)^14 = 1 (mod 7)

Comment: $125^{14} ≡ 6^{14} (mod 7)$ because 125 = 7 * 17 + 6, and $6^{14} ≡ 6^{7} ≡ 6 (mod 7) $ because of Fermat's little theorem. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 6^14 = (6^2)^7 = 36 = 1 (mod 7)

Comment: a^p = a (mod p)   put a=6^2   ,  p=7

Comment: you are right, I'm sorrry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26543/discussion-between-scummy-and-mahdokht).

Answer (score 2):

For 2 :

One has
$$\left((2n-1)\left(p-\frac 12\right)-\frac 32\right)m-n-p-np\le 19$$
$$\iff m\le \frac{19+n+p+np}{(2n-1)\left(p-\frac 12\right)-\frac 32}$$
Here, note that $(2n-1)\left(p-\frac 12\right)-\frac 32\gt 0$.

With $2\le m$, one has
$$2\le\frac{19+n+p+np}{(2n-1)\left(p-\frac 12\right)-\frac 32}$$
$$\iff 2\left((2n-1)\left(p-\frac 12\right)-\frac 32\right)\le 19+n+p+np$$
$$\iff (n-1)(p-1)\le 8$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to problem 2) is to let $m=a+2$, $n=b+2$ and $p=c+2$.  The desired inequality becomes

$$2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)+3(a+b+c)\le21$$

so in particular $a+b+c\le7$ with $0\le a,b,c$.  Since these variables are each $2$ less than a prime, the allowed values are $a,b,c\in\{0,1,3,5\}$.  We may as well assume $a\le b\le c$ (and then permute the results to get all solutions).  The $(a,b,c)$ triples that satisfy the displayed inequality are $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(0,0,3)$, $(0,0,5)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(0,1,3)$, and $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: If I didn't the calculations wrong, I've obtained $2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)+3(a+b+c)≤21$. Nevermind, I understand the principle, so thanks! It's more compact than the other solution described here for this problem (which worked too).

Comment: @scummy, yes, you did the calculation correctly.  I fixed my error.  I'm glad you checked it.  (Fortunately, it didn't affect the resulting solutions -- unless I made another error or two....)